# SSRS 2016 Report Schedule - T-SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I've several SSRS subscriptions set up which are run on demand via (this just triggers a pre-existing schedule)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job = '0B5B5AB1-F475-4478-A3DA-3D602C4FDA4C'
```

What I'd ideally like to do is have one SSRS subscription that I can pass multiple times with different parameter values via a stored procedure, currently the values are set up in the subscription itself.

As an example, I have a report with a `@Client` parameter and 3 clients, 123, 124 and 125.

So I run a stored procedure that would execute the SSRS subscription and pass the specified parameter. ie - 123. Example below-

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job = '0B5B5AB1-F475-4478-A3DA-3D602C4FDA4C' @Client = 123
```

however I cannot find a method that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not have understood your problem fully, so apologies in advance if I take you down a rabbit hole. Having said that..

Given your situation, this is how I would set up my reports and their subscriptions.

I would place parameter `@Client` in the report, and get it's values from a table lets call it `Client_Table` that contains one attribute `ClientCode`, which will drive what data is selected in the report.

I would then create a stored procedure which will have `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job = '0B5B5AB1-F475-4478-A3DA-3D602C4FDA4C'` nested inside it, but would truncate the table that contains the values of `@Client`, for only the client that you want that particular execution of the report for. Something like this..

```
create proc ProcNameHere @ClientID int

as

truncate table Client_table --Truncate values from previous run

Insert Client_Table 
Select @ClientID --add ClientID for this run

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job = '0B5B5AB1-F475-4478-A3DA-3D602C4FDA4C' -- run the report that takes clientid from Client_ID table
```

Let me know if this is what you meant.

This way you can use `EXEC ProcNameHere '123'` to run the report for client 123, as that will be the only entry in the table that is driving the client selection within the report.

Comment: Yeah you have understood me, had a epiphany over the weekend and came up with something very similar! Creating a default parameter table and then changing the value for each on in a cursor on a flat table so that each time the subscription runs, the default parameter has changed.